# how can do make random boolean not repeat itself?

Tags: java, random, boolean

Hey I have a Boolean randomly generating true to false but its always duplicating (true, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true)

how can I make it just switch every time (true, false, true, false, true)

someone please help me or have a different solution that can help me with this, ty

*reset = r.nextBoolean();*

Comment: Switching isn't that random...

Answer (score 4):

Use the bitwise XOR operator.

```
boolean reset = true;
reset ^= true; // do this every time you want to switch
```

It has the benefit of not needing to repeatedly type out the variable.

Comment: Did not know this was valid code to flip a boolean. Interesting.

Comment: While I'm having trouble finding the reference (and its a fractional micro optimization), the `^= true` is the fastest of the various ways to flip a boolean's state.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean reset = false;

reset = !reset;
//...
reset = !reset;
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
 bool myBool;
 if(i % 2 == 0) { myBool= true; }
 else { myBool= false; }
}
```

Insert code where necessary. How exactly is this random?

Comment: There's never a need for the `if (...) ... true else ... false` pattern. Just use `myBool = i % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Obviously. `myBool` shouldn't be used at all, I just wanted to clearly outline where the code for true/false should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    return i % 2 == 0;
```